# How to correctly deal with lib-symlinks in modern Ubuntu versions?

Tags: package-management, 20.04, libraries, 20.10, dynamic-linking

Let's assume that I have some problems with dynamic linking.
I may have some locally built (or manually copied) library which overrides library from APT. The library is not placed to `/usr/local/lib`, so it is hard to differ it from others.

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I can run `ldd` and then parse its output by something like

```
export EXE=/usr/bin/mc;

dpkg -S $(ldd $EXE | grep -v "=>" | awk '{print $1}') 2> /tmp/not-from-apt
dpkg -S $(ldd $EXE | grep "=>" | awk '{print $3}') 2>> /tmp/not-from-apt
```

and then analyze contents of `/tmp/not-from-apt` file. For non-broken 18.04 LTS system this file will contain only one line:

> ```
> $ cat /tmp/not-from-apt 
> dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *linux-vdso.so.1*
> ```

and it is expected as core library, not came from any package.

But the above method will fail on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, here the `/tmp/not-from-apt` file will contain wrong results starting from line 2:

> ```
> $ cat /tmp/not-from-apt 
> dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *linux-vdso.so.1*
> dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpm.so.2
> dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1
> dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
> dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
> dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20
> ```

I suppose that this is happened because of symlinks like shown below:

> ```
> $ ls -al / | grep lib
> lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root       7 Jan 19 04:01 lib -> usr/lib
> lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root       9 Jan 19 04:01 lib32 -> usr/lib32
> lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root       9 Jan 19 04:01 lib64 -> usr/lib64
> lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root      10 Jan 19 04:01 libx32 -> usr/libx32
> ```

Really there is another problem here - some packages have `/lib*` in their filelists, while some have `/usr/lib*`. So this will add an extra mess.

What should I change in my method for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and newer to get correct lines in my `/tmp/not-from-apt` file?

Comment: Run `realpath` on the paths before feeding them to `dpkg`. Also lookup: the UsrMerge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With muru's recommendation we should use `realpath` command. This happens because of [usrmerge](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge).

But with small note that running `realpath` on the earliest stage will not work as expected.

So we need to add one extra step to process the output file:

```
dpkg -S $(realpath $(grep -E "/lib.*" --only-matching /tmp/not-from-apt)) 2> /tmp/not-from-apt-final
```

And the complete method for 20.04 LTS will look as follows:

```
export EXE=/usr/bin/mc;

dpkg -S $(ldd $EXE | grep -v "=>" | awk '{print $1}') 2> /tmp/not-from-apt
dpkg -S $(ldd $EXE | grep "=>" | awk '{print $3}') 2>> /tmp/not-from-apt

dpkg -S $(realpath $(grep -E "/lib.*" --only-matching /tmp/not-from-apt)) 2> /tmp/not-from-apt-final
```

it will produce empty `/tmp/not-from-apt-final` file when there are no errors.
Also one can always check the contents of `/tmp/not-from-apt` for extra info.

---

Below is the case when one has output of `ldd` from some other system saved as `/tmp/ldd-output`, so packages are not installed locally. Here one needs to use `apt-file search` instead of `dpkg -S` as implemented in the [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/N0rbert/423d9b5c8718c45a699e9d3bd406ffc6)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update

cd /tmp
wget -c https://gist.githubusercontent.com/N0rbert/423d9b5c8718c45a699e9d3bd406ffc6/raw/2ce8e747795b74d67a00b96d840626bd95409ad3/apt-file_ldd_parse.sh
chmod +x apt-file_ldd_parse.sh
./apt-file_ldd_parse.sh /tmp/ldd-output | grep Warning
```

to get something like shown below for [this question about 21.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/1374621/66509):

> Warning: configured repositories does not contain 'linux-vdso.so.1' library.
> Warning: configured repositories does not contain '/usr/lib/dcaenabler/libcurl.so.4' library.
> Warning: configured repositories does not contain '/usr/lib/dcaenabler/libssl.so.1.1' library.
> Warning: configured repositories does not contain '/usr/lib/dcaenabler/libcrypto.so.1.1' library.
> Warning: configured repositories does not contain 'libldap_r-2.4.so.2' library.
> Warning: configured repositories does not contain 'liblber-2.4.so.2' library.

Note: `linux-vdso.so.1` is not a problem, it is virtual.