# Cant open qt based applications

Tags: 20.04, qt, shared-library, qt5, qbittorrent

cant open qt based applications such as qbittorrent, nomacs, etc . Getting error:

nomacs: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

qbittorrent: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

SOLVED :: `sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5widgets5 libqt5gui5 libqt5dbus5 libqt5network5 libqt5core5a`
This solved the problem

Output of ldd for qbittorrent:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe988ee000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8af08ad000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f8af05d7000)
    libtorrent-rasterbar.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.10 (0x00007f8af0178000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8af0155000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f8aefaba000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f8aef4cf000)
    libQt5DBus.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007f8aef431000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f8aef270000)
    libQt5Xml.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0x00007f8aef22e000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f8aeea38000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8aee856000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8aee707000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8aee6ea000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8aee4f8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8af123a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8aee4f2000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f8aee45f000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f8aee3d7000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f8aee39f000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f8aee298000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f8aee247000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => not found
    libicuuc.so.56 => not found
    libicudata.so.56 => not found
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8aee240000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8aee117000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f8aee05f000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f8aee02b000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f8aedf6c000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f8aedf3d000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f8aede8e000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f8aede1b000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f8aedcde000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8aedcd3000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f8aedca8000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f8aedc87000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f8aedb69000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f8aedb3f000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f8aedb1c000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f8aedb14000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f8aedb0c000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f8aedaf2000)
```

Ouput of ldd /usr/bin/nomacs

```
ldd /usr/bin/nomacs
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd41fa6000)
    libnomacsCore.so.3 => /usr/lib/nomacs/libnomacsCore.so.3 (0x00007fd5d97ea000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd5d95f4000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007fd5d8f59000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fd5d896e000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fd5d8178000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd5d815d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd5d7f69000)
    libexiv2.so.27 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexiv2.so.27 (0x00007fd5d7c5e000)
    libraw.so.19 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw.so.19 (0x00007fd5d7b7e000)
    libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2 (0x00007fd5d75d7000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007fd5d7556000)
    libquazip5.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquazip5.so.1 (0x00007fd5d7523000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fd5d7360000)
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007fd5d72e7000)
    libQt5Concurrent.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so.5 (0x00007fd5d72de000)
    libQt5Svg.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so.5 (0x00007fd5d7282000)
    libopencv_core.so.4.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.4.2 (0x00007fd5d6ed2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd5d6d83000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd5d6d5e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd5d9bd4000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fd5d6cd6000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fd5d6c9e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd5d6c82000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fd5d6b7d000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => not found
    libicuuc.so.56 => not found
    libicudata.so.56 => not found
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd5d6b75000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd5d6b70000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd5d6a47000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fd5d6a17000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007fd5d6992000)
    liblcms2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2 (0x00007fd5d6937000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007fd5d68f5000)
    libwebp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007fd5d688b000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007fd5d67e0000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fd5d67b7000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007fd5d65a9000)
    libtbb.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2 (0x00007fd5d6563000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007fd5d64ab000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007fd5d6475000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fd5d63b6000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fd5d6389000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fd5d6316000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fd5d61d9000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fd5d61ad000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fd5d61a7000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fd5d619f000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fd5d6185000)
```

Output of `dpkg -S $(realpath $(grep -E "/lib.*" --only-matching /tmp/not-from-apt)) 2> /tmp/not-from-apt-final` for qbittorrent

```
libssl1.1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
libtorrent-rasterbar10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.10.0.0
libqt5widgets5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.12.8
libqt5gui5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.12.8
libqt5dbus5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5.12.8
libqt5network5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5.12.8
libqt5xml5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5.12.8
libqt5core5a:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.12.8
libstdc++6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
libssl1.1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
libgl1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
libpng16-16:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16.37.0
libharfbuzz0b:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0.20600.4
libglib2.0-0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.6400.6
libglib2.0-0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6
libglvnd0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
libglx0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0.0.0
libfreetype6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.17.1
libgraphite2-3:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3.2.1
libx11-6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
liblz4-1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.9.2
libgcrypt20:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.2.5
libxcb1:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
libxau6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
libxdmcp6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
libbsd0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0.10.0
```

Comment: How "qbittorrent, nomacs, etc" were installed? Did you compile Qt on this machine some time before? Please add the output of `ldd $(which qbittorrent) | grep local` and `ldd $(which nomacs) | grep local` to  the question.

Comment: From apt. Those programs were working before. I didnt compiled qt though i did try to run qt designer, so i copied some files like libicui18n.so.56 and others to lib. I think that may have caused the problem. but i did removed all those files that i copied.

Comment: Output of `aptitude search ~o` maybe useful. The strange thing there is that libicui18n.so.56 is not provided by any current Ubuntu version.

Comment: Try the method from https://askubuntu.com/a/1313596/66509 for both qbittorrent an nomacs and report back.

Comment: You probably caused this problem when *"so i copied some files like libicui18n.so.56 and others to lib"*. Did you `cp` or `mv` the files? Did you later delete the files that you moved/copied to /lib? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: You said you removed the files you copied to *lib*, did you restore the files that were there before hand?   If you know the names of the files you overwrote, you can ask the system which packages contains them, and thus know which packages to re-install.. but *some files* is rather vague...  20.04.2 uses the LTS version of Qt5 (5.12.8); so that is the version that needs to be restored there

Comment: Find out which package provides the missing files with e.g. `dpkg -S libicuuc.so.56`. Reinstall with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install packagename`.

Comment: @heynnema Yeah, I used cp to copy them. Then I deleted them later.

Comment: @guiverc I didn't restore them, but I remember that those files weren't there in the beginning

Comment: @N0rbert I have added the output in the edit

Comment: Please post contents of `/tmp/not-from-apt-final`, it is essential part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling libqt5 packages solved the problem

`sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5widgets5 libqt5gui5 libqt5dbus5 libqt5network5 libqt5core5a`

Answer (score 0):

In `terminal`...

`sudo apt update`

<strike>`sudo apt install libicu56` or `sudo apt reinstall libicu56`</strike>

`sudo apt reinstall nomacs qbittorrent`

`reboot`

Retry nomacs and qbittorrent.

**Note**: You may need to reinstall 20.04 to fix this problem.

**Note**: Don't play with system files in /usr and /lib

Comment: It gives error ```E: Unable to locate package libicu56```

Comment: @xenos You're correct. I searched and couldn't find libicu56 either. Darn. I've updated my answer with new suggestions that you may not have tried already. Report back.

Comment: @xenos Status please...

Comment: It didnt work. But reinstalling libqt5 solved the problem

Comment: @xenos Thanks for the update! Glad you got it fixed.