# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'

Tags: python

I have made a docker file that to run in Kubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. The problem is that I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

I followed many tutorials such as this one:
[Installing libgdal-dev on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267844/installing-libgdal-dev-on-ubuntu-20-04/1302161#1302161)
and more specific these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libpq-dev
sudo apt install gdal-bin
sudo apt install libgdal-dev
```

and many others, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852857/no-module-named-osgeo-ogr

but nothing changed and I still face the same error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Where are you getting this error?  Is it when you are in your Docker, or when you are launching Docker?

Comment: When I run the docker.

Comment: Using the `pip install` or `pip3 install` you have to be in the same folder as your Docker when you install the module, or it will not find it.